# Omit aliases in roxygen2

Tags: r, roxygen2

I want to document multiple functions in single help page using `roxygen2` but I want to have only a single alias to the help page i.e. `General` listed in the index. Is it possible?

An example:

```
#' General functions
#' @name General
NULL

#' @rdname Foo
foo <- function() NULL

#' @rdname Bar
bar <- function() NULL
```

How to omit `foo` and `bar` aliases from the package documentation index?

Real life example here would be single `Arithmetic` alias for documenting different functions (`+`, `-`, `/`, `*` etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself: you simply don't export those and make a function-independent documentation page:

```
#' General functions
#'
#' @usage
#' foo()
#' bar()
#'
#' @name General
NULL

#' @export
foo <- function() NULL

#' @export
bar <- function() NULL
```